# How to add this code on facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-gameroom

Our game will soon be launched on Facebook(Gameroom and Webgame), and I have seen a sentence below, can you tell me what I should do with this? should I add a code? or can I set on developers' console without adding this code?

If your game is cross-platform and also available on Facebook Web, you need to detect and support the Gameroom client by detecting an additional user-agent string (e.g., FacebookCanvasDesktop [FBAN/GamesWindowsDesktopApp; FBAV/1.3.0.0]).

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/gameroom

Best
Fiona

Comment: If you serve both web and gameroom from the same URL, then you need to detect which case it actually is - is this just a web user visiting your game in their browser, or are they using the gameroom client? Your code needs to detect this, and then act accordingly (by enabling gameroom-specific features or not.)

Comment: 1. gameroom is supposed to be a client, correct? so would you tell me why gameroom and web game have the same URL?     2.I understand that you are telling me this code can help me to figure out where players come from, but I can understand where players come from via Unity actually. so do I still have to add this code? if I do not add it, can I reach the standard of submission.

Comment: 1. If you are using Gameroom and Web Games platform at the same time, then they simply share one URL to load the actual game from. 2. If your app has other means to correctly identify that it was loaded into Gameroom and behave accordingly, then you probably don’t need to implement an extra check that determines the same thing in a different way.

Comment: thank you so much, hummm, then, why "adding this code is a must have condition to launch on Facebook (gameroom)" as for me, this code is not necessary.